# How to release the memory pointed by a static pointer in a C++ class

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-leaks, static

```
#pragma once // Link.h

#include <memory>
template <typename E>
class Link
{
private:
    static Link<E> * freelist; // Pointer to the freelist head
                              // How to release the memory??

public:
    E element;
    Link *next;

    Link(const E &eleval, Link *nextval = nullptr)
        : element(eleval)
        , next(nextval) {}
    Link(Link *nextval = nullptr) : next(nextval) {}

    /*~Link()
    {
        while (freelist->next != nullptr)
        {
            Link<E> *tmp = freelist;
            freelist = freelist->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }
*/
    void *operator new(size_t)
    {
        if (freelist == nullptr) return ::new Link;
        Link<E>* temp = freelist;
        freelist = freelist->next;
        return temp;
    }

    void operator delete(void* ptr)
    {
        ((Link<E>*)ptr)->next = freelist;
        freelist = (Link<E>*)ptr;
    }
};

template <typename E>
Link<E>* Link<E>::freelist = nullptr;
```

There is a static pointer in the class Link aimed to store the freelist in my linked list, and I want to free the memory of this freelist after the program end. How can I delete the memory of this freelist.

PS: I tried to free the memory like this:

```
/*~Link()
    {
        while (freelist->next != nullptr)
        {
            Link<E> *tmp = freelist;
            freelist = freelist->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }
*/
```

But the program terminated for no reason.

Comment: My recommendation is that you refactor your code so you don't have to. Instead of creating your own list using pointers, why not use [a standard container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)? Perhaps `static std::list<Link<E>> freelist;`?

Comment: `operator new` should not create an object, only return a pointer to a block of memory of the specified size; "operator new" is just a funny way of spelling "allocate" without reserving another identifier. (And `::new` is not the same as `::operator new`.) An object will be constructed in the memory it returns, possibly causing havoc as the object that you already put there is never destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

> But the program terminated for no reason.

Let's have a look at that loop. Here you delete the item:

```
delete freelist;
```

And then, after you deleted it, you access it in the loop condition:

```
while (freelist->next != nullptr)
```

That's undefined behavior. You're accessing an element that you deleted. I would suggest instead doing recursion, traversing the list and deleting the elements on the way out. Perhaps something like

```
/** Delete a link and all the ones after it as well */
void recursiveDelete()
{
    if (next){
        next->recursiveDelete();
    }
    delete this;
}
```

And then call that on `freelist`. Also, you need to remove the following overload:

```
void operator delete(void* ptr)
    {
        ((Link<E>*)ptr)->next = freelist;
        freelist = (Link<E>*)ptr;
    }
```

So if I understand this right, when you delete a `Link`, you set the `next` of the link (which is about to be deleted anyway, so that does nothing) and then you set `freelist` to that link that will now become invalid. This will mess with deleting the items.

As Christophe pointed out, deleting an large list like that might lead to a stack overflow. It's possible to avoid that by using an algorithm that doesn't use recursion. You could try something like this:

```
/** Delete a link and all the ones after it as well */
void deleteAll()
{
    std::vector<Link*> links;
    Link* toDelete = this;
    while (toDelete) {
        links.push_back(toDelete);
        toDelete = toDelete->next;
    }
    for (Link* i : links) {
        delete i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good start! But you need to complete your answer:  the OP's code deletes the free list every time a Link is destroyed (even without dynamic allocation), so that all subsequent call to new will be UB as well.  Now recursive delete is nice but might cause a stack overflow on large lists.

Comment: True that. So the suggestion would be to get rid of the overloaded `delete`, then?

Comment: Right, I tried your version of releasing the memory, but I got the same result, the program terminated

Comment: Alright, I'll change the wording then to make it clear that the `delete` overlaod needs to be removed.